# Published ASP.NET app sending me to "App is up and running, time to take next step to deploy"

Tags: azure, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have a student account through azure. I have hosted several assignments onto azure by publishing them through Visual Studio. I have a plan on azure with the $100 free credit and still have plenty of funds left. I have published my assignments many times with no issues. Lately, it will take the same process and say that it has finished and given me a link to my site. When I click the link it takes me to a page that says "Hey, App Service developers! Your app service is up and running.Time to take the next step and deploy your code."

I have never had this happen before. When I go to my account it shows all my deployed sites and the correct plan affiliated with them. Why are these suddenly doing this? Even when I try to follow the steps, it does not work. I am following the same process I have been doing for the other published applications. Some of them link to my sites just fine but several of them take me to this weird page. I can't submit my assignment links like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something changed in your deployment process, refer following document for publishing app in Azure using Visual 2017

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2019#publish-to-app-service---visual-studio-2017-and-later